# Why is MPLS label added between layer 2 header and layer 3 header of OSI model and not between headers of layer 3 and 4 of OSI model?

Tags: networking, mpls, osi, packet-path, switching-modes

Is there a possibility to use any other two OSI model layers' middle positions? What is the basic concept of switching of packets with MPLS on layer 2.5 of OSI Reference model?

Comment: Is that a practical problem you are asking about (then please add further details) or rather a hypothetical question?

Answer (score 4):

MPLS is a layer-2 protocol. However, no layer-1 carries MPLS directly, so it gets tacked on to various other layer-2 protocols. (hence "layer-2.5") Adding it after a layer-3 header would make no sense as the entire point was to eliminate the overhead of IP routing.